# Exceção StackOverflowError ocorrendo em relacionamento @ManyToMany com JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

Estou tendo um problema em um relacionamento de entidades @ManyToMany. Quando vou tentar fazer uma query simples na entidade que contém o @ManyToMany ocorre um stackOverflow.

Minha regra é simples: Minha entidade AplicacaoClienteVO pode acessar N WebserviceVO e um WebserviceVO pode ser acessado por N AplicacaoClienteVO. As classes estão mapeadas da seguinte forma:

**AplicacaoClienteVO**

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "loaders_sch", name = "ws_aplicacoes_clientes")
public class AplicacaoClienteVO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3401460653428856555L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "nome_aplicacao", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "usuario", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String usuarioAcesso;

    @Column(name = "descricao", nullable = true)
    private String descricao;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinTable(name = "ws_app_ws", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "app_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "webservice_id") })
    private Set<WebserviceVO> webservices;

    @Column(name = "ativo", nullable = false)
    private Boolean ativo;

    @Column(name = "data_criacao", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Calendar dataCriacao;

    @Column(name = "data_atualizacao", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Calendar dataAtualizacao;

    .. getters e setters omitidos
```

**WebserviceVO**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ws_webservices", schema = "loaders_sch")
public class WebserviceVO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2724837366463353708L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "nome", nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "aplicacao", nullable = true)
    private String aplicacao;

    @Column(name = "descricao", nullable = true)
    private String descricao;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "webservices", targetEntity = AplicacaoClienteVO.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    private Set<AplicacaoClienteVO> appCliente;

    @Column(name = "wsdl_url", nullable = false)
    private String wsdlUrl;

    @Column(name = "data_criacao", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Calendar dataCriacao;

    @Column(name = "data_atualizacao", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Calendar dataAtualizacao;

    ...getters e setters omitidos
```

A query que faço que ocorre stackoverflow é a mais simples: `select app from AplicacaoClienteVO app where app.id = :id` por exemplo.

A tabela intermediário gerada (gerada pelo próprio Hibernate) ficou assim:

```
create table WS_APP_WS
(
  app_id        NUMBER(19) not null,
  webservice_id NUMBER(19) not null
)

alter table WS_APP_WS
  add constraint FK_E8YDQBFHUYU2Y1KKYU9YCKARB foreign key (APP_ID)
  references WS_APLICACOES_CLIENTES (ID);
alter table WS_APP_WS
  add constraint FK_5E67UP74MTMPYWJQVQQENCOPN foreign key (WEBSERVICE_ID)
  references WS_WEBSERVICES (ID);
```

Meus mapeamentos estão errados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ricardo, você gerou os métodos `toString()`, `hashCode()` e `equals()` ? Se sim, verifique como eles estão implementados, porque nestes casos haverá uma referência circular dentro destes métodos, gerando o stackoverflow.
Ao meu ver o mapeamento está correto. só confirme esse detalhe adicional por favor !

Abraços

Comment: Gerei sim, gerei de forma automática pelo gerador do Eclipse. O que você recomenda?

Comment: @RicardoGiaviti oque acontece é que você tem uma referência circular(método de uma classe chama o método de outra, infinitamente), não sei seu nível de conhecimento, mas de qualquer forma: Se você remover todas as referencias do `Set<WebserviceVO> webservices;` dentro dos métodos `hashCode()`,`toString()` e `equal()` da sua classe `AplicacaoClienteVO ` deverá funcionar. Porém não é o correto pois senão ao comparar seus objetos, você poderá ter um resultado as vezes errado, já que que `hashCode()` e `equals()` não possuem todas as propriedades definidas.

Comment: @Josue é melhor colocar isso na resposta, é a parte mais importante dela.